# How to fetch xml values from a http get response in java

Tags: java, xml, get, response

I have a Java web service that makes a get request and expects a XML response:

My sample code is shown below. However, I am not able to consume or fetch the xml values from the response.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "send")
public class send {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "recieveFromPhpPortal")
    public String recieveFromPhpPortal(@WebParam(name = "name") String DATE, String MSISDN, String PIN) throws IOException {

        // Step 1: Construct URL"
        String parameters = "VENDOR=D-MXXX&REQTYPE=EXRCTRFREQ&DATA=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                + "            <ns0:COMMAND\n"
                + "                xmlns:ns0=\"http://safaricom.co.ke/Pinless/keyaccounts/\">\n"
                + "                <ns0:TYPE>EXRCTRFREQ</ns0:TYPE>\n"
                + "                <ns0:DATE>" + DATE + "</ns0:DATE>\n"
                + "                <ns0:EXTNWCODE>SA</ns0:EXTNWCODE>\n"
                + "                <ns0:MSISDN>" + MSISDN + "</ns0:MSISDN>\n"
                + "                <ns0:PIN>" + PIN + "</ns0:PIN>\n"
                + "            </ns0:COMMAND>";

        String url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/?" + URLEncoder.encode(parameters, "UTF-8");

        // Step 2: Call API Url
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            // Step 3: Check the response status
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                //If response status == 200
                System.out.println("The XML HAS been SENT!");
                System.out.println("Response Message : " + con.getResponseMessage());

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                //print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                //How do I get the XML response and insert into a database

            } else {
                // print the error received from server
                System.out.println("Error in accessing API - " +responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return "Request Received by the webservice For Processing";
    }
}
```

The XML response I am getting after `System.out.println(response.toString());` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<COMMAND> 
    <TYPE>EXRCTRFRESP</TYPE>            
    <TXNSTATUS>Transaction Status</TXNSTATUS >
    <DATE>Date and time</DATE>
    <EXTREFNUM>Unique</EXTREFNUM>
    <TXNID><PreTUPS Transaction ID></TXNID>
    <MESSAGE>Transaction Message</MESSAGE>
</COMMAND>
```

Someone please direct me on how I can fetch the data from the response and save in a database or at least fetch these response values `TYPE`, `EXTREFNUM`, `MESSAGE` .

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use built-in java library org.w3c.dom. Here is short example:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("staff.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
            System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

And staff.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```